# Unknown column 'tb_application.iID' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

i have two table named tb_application and IndustryTable. tb_application has a foreign key on column named appComp that will referenced to IndustryTable on its ID named iID. to get clear view on this query i attached a photo of the table design in mysql. [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve1Si.png)

i created a query as below:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_application 
            LEFT JOIN IndustryTable on tb_application.iID = IndustryTable.appComp
            where appID = 'A18CS0012'
```

but it returned NULL and the when i run the query on mysql it said

> #1054 - Unknown column 'tb_application.iID' in 'on clause'

i dont know the solution since i am still beginner in ph and mysql. i hope someone can help me thank you.

Comment: Please show us the schema! Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: I think you just mixed up the field names as according to you picture tb_application table has appComp field and IndustryTable has iID, which explains the error message you are getting.

Comment: @Shadow i just follow the syntax like this 'SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;'

Comment: It's not your syntax that's wrong, just the field names belong to the other table. Pls check your own screenshot!

Comment: perhaps : `SELECT * FROM tb_application tb LEFT JOIN IndustryTable it on it.iID=tb.appComp where tb.appID = 'A18CS0012'`

Comment: i already got it. hahhaha thanks guys